# Changing x-axis labels in plotCI

Tags: r

I am plotting confidence intervals in R using `plotCI()` from `plotrix`. I am having trouble changing the x-axis labels to strings. Below is my code:

```
f<-c(6.244452347,6.020655083,6.074430153,6.164744349,6.382905979,6.195971068) 
L<-c(6.209330016,5.986852279,6.032932041,6.124849263,6.293097298,6.09968182)
U<-c(6.279574678,6.054457887,6.115928266,6.204639434,6.472714661,6.292260317)
plotCI(1:6,f,ui=U,li=L,col="red",scol="blue")
```

I want to change the 1:6 to a:f if possible and have tried a few things but haven't found a solution. In addition, if I could make the y axis range from 0 that would be helpful too.

Comment: You didn't specify the package (which you should have), but [`gplots::plotCI`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gplots/docs/plotCI) has arguments for axis labels, and `plotrix::plotCI` has an example of how to do this in its [help file](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plotrix/docs/plotCI).

Comment: I see where it specifies how to label points and add a label to the whole axis, but I don't see where it would tell me how to change 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 to a, b, c, d, e, f. I'm relatively new to R so maybe I'm just missing it.

Comment: Which package are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f <- c(6.244452347,6.020655083,6.074430153,6.164744349,
    6.382905979,6.195971068)
L <- c(6.209330016,5.986852279,6.032932041,6.124849263,
     6.293097298,6.09968182)
U <- c(6.279574678,6.054457887,6.115928266,6.204639434,6.472714661,
      6.292260317)
library("plotrix")
par(las=1)  ## cosmetic: horizontal y-axis labels are nicer
plotCI(1:6,f,ui=U,li=L,col="red",scol="blue",
       axes=FALSE,   ## disable axes (including tick labels)
       xlab="",      ## suppress x-axis label
       ylim=c(0,7)   ## specify y-axis limits
   )
axis(side=2)         ## add default y-axis (ticks+labels)
axis(side=1,at=1:6,  ## add custom x-axis
     label=letters[1:6])
box(bty="l")         ## add box
```